# performing `cat` results in `Value too large for defined data type error`

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I performed cat on a file in /proc/(pid)/map and got the error  `Value too large for defined data type error`

Of course the file is binary and I suppose its not the best idea to output a binary file into a terminal but I was actually redirecting the output to a tr command to translate the binary into plain text.

It does not happen on all map files. Only a few.

I am curious as to why cat would issue such an error.

My system is a solaris 10 box running on Sun Fire V890.

Comment: What's the output from `truss -f -a -vall -o /path/to/output/file cat /proc/(pid)/map` for a file that causes the error?  You should see a system call that fails with EOVERFLOW.

Comment: The output is here: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user40_Xu2OP1zHiL_0.py

Comment: This is the second time in the past week or so I've seen an EOVERFLOW error question posted from reading from Solaris `/proc/(pid)/map`.  Look at the source for pargs to see how it's done in a Solaris utility:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pargs/pargs.c

Comment: I've actually looked at the source, but for a separate reason. This particular question here is about cat which  should be an unstructured dump of contents of a file. Why should cat be bothered with an overflow is the question.

Comment: Because the "file" isn't really a file.  If you look at the truss output you posted, a `read()` of 8kB from the start of a "file" that the previous `stat()` call shows to be about 26kB in size (IIRC) fails with EOVERFLOW. Something else is going on.  You could use `dtrace` to figure out what.  It's almost certainly well documented in Oracle's Solaris documentation, but good luck figuring out where.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> **Value too large for defined data type**
>
> **Cause**
>
> The user ID or group ID of
> an IPC object or file system object was too large to be stored in an
> appropriate member of the caller-provided structure.
>
> **Action**
>
> Run the
> application on a newer system, or ask the program’s author to fix this
> condition.
>
> **Technical Notes**
>
> This error occurs only on systems that
> support a larger range of user or group ID values than a declared
> member structure can support. This condition usually occurs because
> the IPC or file system object resides on a remote machine with a
> larger value of type uid_t, off_t, or gid_t than that of the local
> system. The symbolic name for this error is EOVERFLOW, errno=79.

Or put another way: code asking for data using a structure with 32bit values when the source data is 64bit and the actual values are higher than what can fit in 32bits.

Comment: why would that be an issue for a `cat`? All that `cat` is supposed to do is dump the contents of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the other answer is correct. But what is happening is `cat` attempts to open the file you're trying to read, and calls `(f)stat` which is where the problem lies (you can see this by running `strace cat <file>`).

You're on a 32 bit operating system which means if your file size is larger than that(2^31) bytes this will always happen (i.e. if it doesn't fit in a signed 32 bit integer). Try to `ls -l` your file and look at the size and you'll see

Comment: *You're on a 32 bit operating system*  No. Not at all. That has nothing to do with this question.  The problem stated in this question is caused by the way the Solaris kernel presents `/proc`.  Some files there can't be `read()` like a normal file.  Note also that even 32-bit Solaris is fully large-file capable, to the point that even on 64-bit Solaris most of the tools such as `ls` and `cat` are actually 32-bit binaries.  Solaris has no problem whatsoever running 32-bit binaries on 64-bit kernels. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1474/largefile-5.html